# How can I upload my login information to riverpo when the user logs in?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I listen to my user with ChanceNotifier in Riverpo. I want to send my user information to ChanceNotifier while logging in.
This is how I call ChanceNotifier in the login service and send my data=>

```
var datam = jsonEncode(response.data!.data);

      ProviderScope.containerOf(context!)
          .read(userProvider.notifier)
          .setUser(datam);
```

The ChanceNotifier codes I prepared are as follows.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_architecture/view/authenticate/login/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class UserNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  User _user = User(
      Id: 0,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      token: '',
      status: false);

  User get user => _user;

  void setUser(String user) {
     _user = User.fromJsonn(user);
    debugPrint("usermaninnnnnnnn :`$_user`");
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setUserFromModel(User user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserNotifier>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier();
});
```

Even though I sent my information to ChanceNotifir while logging in, my data is not added to the User. Whenever I call User, it always returns null.